# How to dynamically add custom types based on selection in Symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm creating a form for ticket reservations for performances in symfony.

Every performance has multiple performance-data. In the db, the performanceData records contains stuff like a date, a location and a list of available ticket types. The available ticket types might differ per performanceData record.

When a user wants to make a reservation, he has to select a performance-data.
Based on this selection, he should get a list with all available ticket types + per ticket type a (number)field to choose the number of tickets. This is where I'm stuck.

I used the symfony documentation to create a dynamic form to load the available ticket types in a dropdown based on the user's selection. But how do I add the list with the available ticket types + number fields? This list should be mapped with the 'tickets' in the Reservation entity.

My entities:

PerformanceData

```
/**
 * PerformanceData
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="performance_data")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class PerformanceData
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $date;

    /**
     * @var Performance
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Performance", inversedBy="performanceData")
     */
    private $performance;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Location
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Location")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="location_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TicketType")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="performance_data_ticket_type",
     *   joinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="performance_data_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   },
     *   inverseJoinColumns={
     *     @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *   }
     * )
     */
    private $availableTicketTypes;

    //getters/setters...

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDisplayText()
    {
        return $this->getPerformance()->getInfoTitle() . ' - ' . strftime('%A %d %B %Y', $this->getDate()->getTimestamp());
    }
}
```

Reservation

```
/**
 * Reservation
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="reservation")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Reservation
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var PerformanceData
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PerformanceData")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="performance_data_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $performanceData;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\ReservationTicket", mappedBy="reservation")
     */
    private $tickets;

    //getters/setters...
}
```

ReservationTicket

```
/**
 * ReservationTicket
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="reservation_ticket")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ReservationTicket
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $numberOfTickets;

    /**
     * @var Reservation
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reservation", inversedBy="tickets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reservation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $reservation;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\TicketType
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TicketType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $ticketType;

    //getters/setters...
}
```

My Reservation Type form

```
/**
 * Class ReservationType
 * @package AppBundle\Form
 */
class ReservationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


        $builder->add('performanceData', EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'label'         => 'Voorstelling',
                    'class'         => 'AppBundle:PerformanceData',
                    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
                        return $this->getOpenReservations($er);
                    },
                    'group_by'      => function ($performanceData) {
                        if ($performanceData instanceof PerformanceData &&
                            $performanceData->getPerformance() instanceof Performance
                        ) {
                            return $performanceData->getPerformance()->getInfoTitle();
                        }

                        return 'Andere voorstellingen';
                    },
                    'choice_label'  => 'displayText',
                    'required'      => true,
                )
            );

        //event listener for ticket types
        $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, PerformanceData $performanceData = null) {
            $availableTicketTypes = array();
            $reservationTickets   = array();

            if ($performanceData instanceof PerformanceData) {
                $availableTicketTypes = $performanceData->getAvailableTicketTypes();
            }

            foreach ($availableTicketTypes as $availableTicketType) {
                $reservationTickets[] =  $availableTicketType->getDisplayText();

                $form->add('tickets', ChoiceType::class, array(
                    'label' => 'tickets',
                    'choices' => $reservationTickets,
                    'mapped' => false
                ));
            }
        };

        $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
                $data = $event->getData();

                $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getPerformanceData(), $data);
            }
        );

        $builder->get('performanceData')->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
            function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
                // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
                // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
                $performanceData = $event->getForm()->getData();

                // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
                // the parent to the callback functions!
                $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $performanceData);
            }
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                'data_class' => Reservation::class
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks!

EDIT:

My question was a bit vague I think. THis is what I want to achieve:

When a user selects a performance-data:

- Load all available ticket types
- Per available ticket type: dynamically add a 'number' input field to add the number of tickets.
- map these fields to tickets in the reservation entity

I have a reservationTicket entity:

```
/**
 * ReservationTicket
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="reservation_ticket")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ReservationTicket
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="amount", type="smallint", nullable=false)
     */
    private $numberOfTickets;

    /**
     * @var Reservation
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Reservation", inversedBy="tickets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="reservation_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $reservation;

    /**
     * @var \AppBundle\Entity\TicketType
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\TicketType")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="ticket_type_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $ticketType;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use dynamically form you should use JavaScript.
As you know Symfony is a PHP framework working on a server side. 
You create your form once time from the controller. The event are calling before submit or after submit... not during client action.
To do what you want you have to get  the performance data value with js and send it (Ajax call) to a controller which it'll returns the available tickets based on performance data. 
And you display available tickets in your form with javascript

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that reservation should be associated with PerformanceData and TicketType(both), so your entity Reservation should have these two fields with associations.

Then you should use EntityType and as class use your entity. Symfony should automatically make choises list:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities
e.g.

```
$builder->add('users', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'AppBundle:User',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->orderBy('u.username', 'ASC');
    },
    'choice_label' => 'username',
));
```

After that you should have 2 choises on your form. You can now hide one of them and if somebody select some value from the first select list, you can show second list with filtered values.

IMHO this should help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! I think my question was a bit vague (my mistake), so I've edited it. :)

Comment: You're welcome. If my answer helped, you can always just vote up ;) Regards